# Cakephp just display a form field without input

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am using CakePHP. I have a form, let's say user profile edit, and I don't want the user to modify the username, but I still want to display it.

I am displaying it using something like:

```
echo $this->Form->input("username");
```

This outputs a label named **Username** and an input text box.
I don't want this text box, instead just want another label with the username value.

Have been going through the cook book, but can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is stored in `$this->data[ 'User' ][ 'username' ]` (assuming the model's name is "User").

On the other hand if you want to just disable the edit box, use this:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'username',
    array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can literally just make an HTML label, and use the value that's passed:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label><?php echo $this->data['User']['username']; ?>
```